# Hikari has no idle connections in pool before the first request

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I want my spring-boot backend to have idle connections to DB.
I do some setting in `application.yml` like:

```
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL_AGGREGATOR}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME_AGGREGATOR}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD_AGGREGATOR}
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      auto-commit: false
      connection-timeout: 1000
      minimum-idle: 30
      maximum-pool-size: 30
```

But when I start the application, seems there is no connection initialized, until the first request to API. And then I can see some logs like:

```
13:10:02.723 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1e42284b
13:10:02.865 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@13533603
13:10:03.010 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2ec851a1
13:10:03.158 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@57fdc7ec
13:10:03.159 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After adding stats (total=30, active=0, idle=30, waiting=0)
13:10:29.016 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=30, active=0, idle=30, waiting=0)
13:10:29.019 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
13:10:59.025 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=30, active=0, idle=30, waiting=0)
13:10:59.027 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
13:11:29.034 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=30, active=0, idle=30, waiting=0)
13:11:29.039 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
13:11:59.042 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=30, active=0, idle=30, waiting=0)
```

Why does this happen? I already set `minimum-idle: 30`, but the pool is not initialized at the beginning.